# How to solve this error: Undefined symbol

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I'm trying to do a simple thing that requires a new package. I write my code basically following a tutorial online, just two things to understand how it works. But when I try to compile it, Lazarus show me this error:

> Error: Undefined symbol: RESSTR_$FPWEB_$$_START$indirect

I suppose it's because I have to rebuilt Lazarus. If so, how do I rebuild it? And if it's because of another thing, can anybody help me? I'm pretty new with Lazarus.

[image]

Comment: Compile everything with exactly the same version,defines and sources.  Somehow things got mixed here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this error! The error was some error during the installation of the package. I just delete it and reinstalled and I solved it.

Comment: If the package already had .o or .ppu's, delete them next time to make this kind of stuff happen rarer.